# How can i enter some data after some regular interval in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Model

`class Account:`

and other model called

`class Transactions:`

Now i have field `interest_rate` in `Account` Model.

I want to pay the interest on 3 month basis from the opening date of account. So
i want the automatic transaction of the required amount applied to the account after every 3 months or depending upon the months specified

How can I achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for starters.

Run a crontab every 3 months: https://serverfault.com/questions/129633/how-to-run-cron-job-every-3-months-in-apache2

Comment: but there can be many users with different dates so i need to run daily . but can i do that without cron job

Comment: Hi. You can set up a cron to run on any schedule, I just provided one example.

Comment: In my opinion the transaction can be evaluated when someone wants to check and see the account, this could trigger a reconciliation of any pending transactions. Unless you plan to use some kind of database views or reports.

Answer (score 0):

A regular job would definitely work, but I don't think doing it every three months is the right approach. Instead, do it every day and query to find out which accounts need processing. Doing it this way, you can use various criteria to decide which accounts to process (you hinted you might need this in the question).

I would set up a standalone python script that had access to Django's models, using [these techniques](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).

I would set up the script to run once per day. Each time it ran, it would do something like:

```
accounts = Account.objects.filter(date_added=<three months ago>).all()
for account in accounts:
    # do what needs to be done
```